# How to loop following group_by

Tags: r

I have the following data frame, which has 3 columns.

Data-frame code:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "inst" = rep(c('a','b','c','d'),4),
  "swi"  = c(rep(0.05,4), rep(0.10,4), rep(0.15,4), rep(0.20,4)),
  "val"  = c(10,12,8,15,11,14,10,15,11,15,13,15,11,15,16,15)
)
```

Data-frame output:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   inst [4]
   inst    swi   val
   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a      0.05    10
 2 b      0.05    12
 3 c      0.05     8
 4 d      0.05    15
 5 a      0.1     11
 6 b      0.1     14
 7 c      0.1     10
 8 d      0.1     15
 9 a      0.15    11
10 b      0.15    15
11 c      0.15    13
12 d      0.15    15
13 a      0.2     11
14 b      0.2     15
15 c      0.2     16
16 d      0.2     15
```

I want to find for each unique 'inst' the 'swi' value, where 'val' value for the current 'swi' value is equal to next one. If this condition is not satisfied for an 'inst', then the output should be '-1'.
In other words, I want to calculate/generate the following:

```
inst  swi
 a    0.1
 b    0.15
 c    -1
 d    0.05
```

How can I generate this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach using `dplyr`. Using `reframe` take the first `swi` where the `diff`erence of `val` is zero, for each `inst`. When this is not present for a given `inst`, there will be `NA` - you can replace this with -1.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  reframe(
    swi = swi[diff(val) == 0][1],
    .by = inst
  ) %>%
  replace_na(list(swi = -1))
```

**Output**

```
  inst   swi
1    a  0.10
2    b  0.15
3    c -1.00
4    d  0.05
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code fulfills the main part of the solution (which is to find the minimum/first 'swi' value, for which the corresponding 'val' value is equal to the one of the next 'swi' value):

```
df %>%
  group_by(inst) %>%
  mutate(next_val = lead(val)) %>%
  filter(next_val == val) %>%
  summarize(ret_swi = min(swi))
```

This one produces the following output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  inst  ret_swi
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 a        0.1 
2 b        0.15
3 d        0.05
```

What is missing is setting 'ret_swi' value to '-1' if there are 'inst's which do not fulfill the condition above.